# Un Hiding all sheets and go to specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have to macro to unhide all sheets but when I run it, it takes me to the bottom of a random sheet. I would like it to go, to a specific sheet and take me to the top of the sheet.

code

```
Sub Unhide_All_Tabs()

For Each ws In Sheets: ws.Visible = True: Next
```

Comment: You can refer to the sheet by name or by index. Just activate it after the loop.

Comment: @brax got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mathieu Guindon and @braX.

This is what I would do too:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Unhide_All_Tabs()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WSht As Worksheet

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each WSht In WB.Worksheets
        WSht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next
    Set WSht = WB.Worksheets("Dashboard")

    WSht.Activate
    WSht.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Unhide_All_Tabs()

For Each ws In Sheets: ws.Visible = True: Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Consider iterating the `Worksheets` collection if you mean to work with `Worksheet` objects. `Sheets` can also contains `Chart` and other sheet types. Also if the "Dashboard" sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook`, give it a code name and do `DashboardSheet.Visible = True` and `DashboardSheet.Activate` and `DashboardSheet.Range("A1").Select` instead of dereferencing the exact same object 3 times off the `Sheets` collection. Also consider writing your loop as an actual code block rather than some golfed-up minified-for-immediate-pane version.

Comment: Unqualified `Sheets` refers to whatever workbook is currently active. You most probably want that to be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: @Jonathan Marin --- Were you satisfied with your own answer at the end from the functionality point of view? Did it work?